# 単一StreamへのFIFOな排他アクセスの方法について

Tags: c#, stream, audio-streaming

現在、C#にて音楽再生アプリを作成しています。
以下の要件を満たすようなStream（もしくはそれに準じるもの）を探しているのですがいまいち見つけられません。

・単一のStreamの末尾にbyte配列を書き込みながら、同時に先頭から読込できる。

書き込み用スレッドと読み込み用スレッドを作成し、
書き込み用スレッドでは5秒程度に分割された音楽ファイルをweb上からHttpリクエストで取得し、byte配列として順次Streamに書き込んでいく。
一方、ストリーミング再生を実現するため、（上記の音楽ファイルのStreamへの書き込みを行う傍ら）、読込用スレッドで先頭からStream上のbyte配列を読込み、再生する。

このような要件を実現したいのですが、いまいちうまくいきません。
MemoryStreamですとFIFOや排他アクセスが実現できず、
Queueですとどうしても再生時に切れ目が出来てしまいます。

標準ライブラリでは無いとしても、継承して実装できれば構いません。
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: .NET Frameworkには[`ConcurrentQueue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/dd267265.aspx)という並行キューが存在します。ただ、前提条件と`Queue`を用いても再生が途切れるという状況をみるに、実装方式が不味いか、バッファ管理設計が適切でない気がします（あくまで邪推です）。

Answer (score 1):

[方法: ローカルのプロセス間通信で匿名パイプを使用する](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/bb546102(v=vs.110).aspx)
本来はプロセス間通信用ですが、`AnonymousPipeServerStream`へ書き込んで、`AnonymousPipeClientStream`から読み出すというのはどうでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

サウンドのストリーミング再生は本質的にはXAudio2などの低レベルな再生キューにアクセスできるAPIを使用する必要があります。C#であればSharpDXなどのラッパーを利用することになるかと思います。